# Fieldset prevents reading values input elements

Tags: jquery, html

The following situation works fine (JSP file):

```
<p class="FormInputElement">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <input type="text" class="description" id="description"/><br />
</p>
<button class="Button75" type="submit" id= "editWidget" alt="Edit widget">
        <img src="/tis/img/icons/tick.png">
                Save
</button>
```

In my Servlet, a .JS file, the description value can be read like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#editWidget").click(function(e){
        var description = $(this).parent().find('.description').val();
```

However, if I put `<fieldset>` tags around the button, the description is always "". The servlet can't read the value anymore. How is this possible? What changes when using a fieldset?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original markup structure is this

- DIV *(or any other container)*

  - P

    - LABEL
    - INPUT#description
  - BUTTON#editWidget

Here `$(this).parent()` would go to the DIV, and `.find()` would work from there, finding the expected element.

With `<fieldset>`, the markup structure changes to

- DIV

  - P

    - LABEL
    - INPUT#description
  - FIELDSET

    - BUTTON#editWidget

Here `$(this).parent()` would go to the FIELDSET, and `.find()` would find nothing.

Solution: Don't use `.parent()`, use `.closest("div")`.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. This makes sense, I should have seen this:p So, the new line would be: var description = $(this).closest("div").find('.description').val(); ?

Comment: @John If the closest container element is a `<div>` - yes. Since your sample does not show it, the `<div>` was a guess on my part.